# how To store "int a" into "int a array" And "int a" having value 12345?

Tags: c#

I want output like this in the C#. I really want to know. please

```
int a = 12345;
int[] B = new int[5];
```

I want output Like:

```
0 : 1;
1 : 2;
2 : 3; 
3 : 4;
4 : 5;
```

Comment: `int[] B = new int[5] {0,1,2,3,4,5}`

Comment: maybe you get u this wrong becoz i want take input from the user and after that i stored it in int a variable and now i want to store in int array using int a. So please Help with that..

Comment: "Split int to int array" Google that

Comment: sir can you tell me how ?

Comment: `var array = a.ToString().Select(c => c-'0').ToArray();` is easiest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use:

```
int a = 12345;
int[] B = a.ToString().ToCharArray().Select(ch => Convert.ToInt32(ch.ToString())).ToArray();
```

or

```
int a = 12345;
int[] B = a.ToString().ToCharArray().Select(ch => int.Parse(ch.ToString())).ToArray();
```

Comment: This is shorter: `var array = a.ToString().Select(c => c-'0').ToArray();`

Comment: @TechnoSuggest, did you get through it?